# How can I pass an translation interpolation variable to a failed form validation message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, simple-form

So, I'm basically trying to show Devise's *confirm_within* time in the error message that comes when clicking the confirmation email link after the required time.

I am using YAML translation files.

The interpolation variable is called `devise_confirm_within`

My YAML is like this:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            email:
              confirmation_period_expired: "some text %{devise_confirm_within}"
```

Normally, I would find the appropriate view, and then pass the interpolation variable as a parameter to the `translate` or `t` method. Like this:

```
<p><%= t("devise.mailer.confirmation_instructions.please_click_the_below_link_to_confirm_your_new_email", :devise_confirm_within => distance_of_time_in_words(0, User.confirm_within, :locale => I18n.locale)) %></p>
```

However, there is no view that has the `confirmation_period_expired` translation key, so I can't do it in this same manner.

I have a view with:

```
<div class="form-inputs">
  <%= f.input :email, :required => true %>
</div>
```

And a user model with:

```
validates :email, uniqueness: true
```

I want to keep all the translation text in the YAML file, so adding :message to the validates field won't do.

So how can I get the devise_confirm_within time into that confirmation_period_expired error message?

PS: I am using the simple_form gem for forms, and also the dotiw gem for overriding the default distance_of_time_in_words method (this doesn't influence this problem I'm having).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was circumvented when I added this to devise.en.yml and similar to the other devise..yml files:

```
en:
  errors:
    messages:
      confirmation_period_expired: "some text %{period}"
```

I however wasn't able to pass a translation interpolation variable to a failed form validation (i.e. add a variable to a devise message), of which I am still curious.